# Downloading files from Sharepoint Online - File Not Found - How to get correct URL for download?

Tags: pnp-powershell, file-download

I'm trying to download files being edited in Microsoft Teams/Sharepoint Online using various examples from the Internet (including the ones here).  Currently I am using the Sharepoint PnP module: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/?view=sharepoint-ps

But all I am getting is "Get-PnPFile : File Not Found."

```
$cn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Site -ReturnConnection
Get-PnPFile -AsFile -Connection $cn -Url $Url -FileName $FileName -Path $Path
```

I am using the link to a file (that people are collaborating in Teams on) copied from the Sharepoint website (following the link from Teams, then getting the link from the file itself) which comes in the form https://oursite.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/foldernamefromteams/longidentifier  I've tried passing that Url with and without the site name.  I don't get an error on the Connect line.  It pops up the username and password prompt.

I think the key is getting the site and/or URL correct, but I don't know how to get the correct URL other than from the link that Sharepoint says is the link to the file.  Pasting that link in the browser does open the Excel sheet (or whatever) for editing in the browser, instead of downloading the file, but I'm not sure what a more "direct" link would be, or how to get it.

Comment: most probably url needs to be server-relative, so try removing `https://oursite.sharepoint.com` from the url...

Comment: @Nils Yes, I have tried it both ways and also both ways using it as either the -Url or the -ServerRelativeUrl parameter

Answer (score 1):

The Link that looks like `https://oursite.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/foldernamefromteams/longidentifier` is the link to the office online server to edit the document. You can not "download" that. You'd need the direct url to the file in SharePoint.

If you're using teams: Open teams, right-klick the file and select "get link" it should look like: `https://[tenant-name].sharepoint.com/sites/[team-name]/documents/[channel-name]/[file-name.ext]` use that with pnp.

Using that url (i.e. `https://[tenant-name].sharepoint.com/sites/[team-name]/documents/[channel-name]/[file-name.ext]`) you can download the file as follows:

```
Connect-PNPOnline https://[tenant-name].sharepoint.com/sites/[team-name]
Get-PNPFile -Url /sites/[team-name]/documents/[channel-name]/[file-name.ext] -AsFile
```

Comment: I did end up finding a URL which worked with actual friendly names of the form: https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[team]/Shared Documents/[folders]/[filename] - where Shared Documents is apparently the correct stand-in for the "Documents" that appears in the interface (and [team] can have a friendly description on the interface which varies from the actual path - in our case extra spaces on the web page)

Comment: Using Teams to find the link as you sugges, however, I either get a "Microsoft Teams" link of form https://teams.microsoft.com/l/file/B60BA4C8... or a Sharepoint link of the form: https://[tenant-name].sharepoint.com/sites/[TeamName]/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?OR=teams&action=edit&sourcedoc={B60BA4C8 ...